# Is it possible to force a GeoPackage to have same coordinate reference system for all tables?

Tags: geopackage

At the creation of GeoPackage, is it possible to define one CRS for every table in GeoPackage? so that later it won't be possible to have layers with different CRS in the same GeoPackage?

Comment: I don't think so, why would you want to?

Comment: We are developing a process in which users would submit their vector and non-vector data for processing to an app using a geopackage template, kind of using geopackage as a forcing schema for consistent inputs. We would pass an empty template gpkg, and users would populate it. Would like to allow users to change the CRS of all layers in one go and then start populating it.

Comment: There are triggers in GeoPackage that requires that SRID used in the data tables must appear in `gpkg_spatial_ref_sys` table. So at least you can make is impossible to create tables with other SRID by leaving just rows for supported SRID into gpkg_spatial_ref_sys.